# Python "import comtypes.client" calls pwd.py indirectly

Tags: python, import

I have not a deep experience in Python. Working on last application found very interesting thing. I put the script with name pwd.py in the same directory as the main script. I created pwd.py to test some basic modules and methods, no more purpose.

But I was really surprised that later found that my main script indirectly calls pwd.py! I put some debug printouts and found that the import statement "import comtypes.client" calls pwd.py.

Well...I thought that it is probably some standard feature that I don't know still, but:

- recursive search in the PYTHON_HOME (C:\Python343 in my case) does not show pwd.py in the standard Python directories. I even tried to do recursive search by file content inside c:\Python343 to find who calls pwd.py, but this search returned nothing (I used Total Commander search by Ctrl+F7, probably it fails sometimes).
- Google says nothing well-known regarding pwd.py

So, what it is the feature and why it is not described well anywhere?
It is even a kind of vulnerability. One can create pwd.py in the same directory where the main script is located and put any code inside pwd.py...

May anybody check this behavior on own system? If it really works so, where I can find the description of this feature?

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior.  Can you provide a self-contained example (maybe with imports, of course) that shows the behavior?

Comment: I removed the `pwd` tag; this question has nothing to do with the `pwd` command the tag belongs to.

Comment: Put a `throw RuntimeError("We got here!")` statement at the top of `pwd.py` and show us the traceback, please.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the line "import comtypes.client" causes this "issue". 
Here is the content of the main script:

```
#!C:\Python343\python
import comtypes.client # this line causes pwd.py to be called indirectly !!!
```

And here is the content of pwd.py that was put to the same directory:

```
#!C:\Python343\python
print('pwd.py is called!')
raise RuntimeError("We got here!") # I put an exception as Kevin asked me above, but I am not sure that Python knows "throw" (it does not work for me) so use "raise"
```

After that I got the following result:

```
c:\dev>test.py
pwd.py is called!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\dev\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import comtypes.client # this line causes pwd.py to be called indirectly !!!
  File "C:\Python343\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from comtypes.client._code_cache import _find_gen_dir
  File "C:\Python343\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_code_cache.py", line 7, in <module>
    import ctypes, logging, os, sys, tempfile, types
  File "c:\Python343\Lib\tempfile.py", line 34, in <module>
    import shutil as _shutil
  File "c:\Python343\Lib\shutil.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pwd import getpwnam
  File "C:\dev\pwd.py", line 3, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError("We got here!")
RuntimeError: We got here!
```

So the call chain is:

```
C:\dev\test.py
C:\Python343\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py
C:\Python343\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_code_cache.py
c:\Python343\Lib\tempfile.py
c:\Python343\Lib\shutil.py
C:\dev\pwd.py
```

and the line "from pwd import getpwnam" seems to be responsible for the call of pwd.py.
After that I changed my main script the following way:

```
#!C:\Python343\python
import pwd # I know it's you!
```

and really, it calls pwd.py! Thanks Kevin for this simple idea.
The only remaining question is is it correct that "import pwd" calls pwd.py from the same directory? Very interesting feature :-)